# Capybara: Filled-in forms and save_and_open_page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara

When I fill forms using capybara and page opens in browser, the fields are empty. Is it normal?

```
page.fill_in 'Email', :with => 'test@gmail.com'
save_and_open_page
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It seems that filling stuff into a text field doesn't make it part of the DOM (specifically, the `value` attribute of the <input> element), so it won't show up in the page you get.

So yes, it looks like this is normal indeed.

Comment: That seems odd to me, because I have been able to see the values filled in up till when I upgraded to capybara 2.0.  When I go back to Capybara 1.1.4, I see them again.